# What is the correct command to install downloaded Ethernet missing firmware saved to USB stick drive?

Tags: software-installation

I installed Debian 9 without DE-desktop environment as I was not connected to the internet by LAN.

I inserted the USB having missing ethernet firmware after the installation and typed the below command in terminal but it says **cannot access archive**

```
dpkg -i /path/to/firmware-netxen_20161130-3_all.deb
```

Am I writing the command correctly?

This firmware is provided by the non-free package firmware-netxen. I installed the missing firmware. Please check the result https://i.stack.imgur.com/exffX.jpg

Is this means I did it and installed it correctly? if yes why is it that when i checked the network using this command.

```
ip route get 1.2.3.4
```

it says

```
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
```

I connected already the LAN cable but still no network.

dmesg shows below

```
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.9.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.9.51-1 (2017-09-28)
[    1.331446] QLogic/NetXen Network Driver v4.0.82
[    1.331548] netxen_nic 0000:06:00.0: 2MB memory map
[    1.331679] netxen_nic 0000:06:00.0: Flash fw[4.0.406] is < min fw supported[4.0.505]. Please update firmware on flash
[    1.331718] netxen_nic: probe of 0000:06:00.0 failed with error -22
[    1.331771] netxen_nic 0000:06:00.1: 2MB memory map
[    1.331901] netxen_nic 0000:06:00.1: Flash fw[4.0.406] is < min fw supported[4.0.505]. Please update firmware on flash
[    1.331936] netxen_nic: probe of 0000:06:00.1 failed with error -22
[    1.331992] netxen_nic 0000:06:00.2: 2MB memory map
[    1.332122] netxen_nic 0000:06:00.2: Flash fw[4.0.406] is < min fw supported[4.0.505]. Please update firmware on flash
[    1.332158] netxen_nic: probe of 0000:06:00.2 failed with error -22
[    1.332211] netxen_nic 0000:06:00.3: 2MB memory map
[    1.332340] netxen_nic 0000:06:00.3: Flash fw[4.0.406] is < min fw supported[4.0.505]. Please update firmware on flash
[    1.332374] netxen_nic: probe of 0000:06:00.3 failed with error -22
[    1.333498] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    1.334366] HP HPSA Driver (v 3.4.16-0)
[    1.334374] hpsa 0000:05:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    1.334439] hpsa 0000:05:00.0: MSI-X capable controller
[    1.334573] hpsa 0000:05:00.0: Logical aborts not supported
[    1.334574] hpsa 0000:05:00.0: HP SSD Smart Path aborts not supported
[    1.336879] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    1.336911] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    1.336925] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    1.336981] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.337632] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.337908] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    1.338140] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.338153] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.338161] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.338174] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: debug port 1
[    1.342062] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    1.342079] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: irq 20, io mem 0xeb8f0000
[    1.359411] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.359491] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.359493] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.359495] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.359497] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.0-4-amd64 ehci_hcd
[    1.359498] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.7
[    1.359809] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.359824] hub 1-0:1.0: 8 ports detected
[    1.360393] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: UHCI Host Controller
[    1.360406] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.360415] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: detected 2 ports
[    1.360437] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: irq 20, io base 0x00001000
[    1.360845] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.360848] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.360850] usb usb2: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    1.360851] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.0-4-amd64 uhci_hcd
[    1.360853] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    1.361186] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.361252] hub 2-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    1.361825] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: UHCI Host Controller
[    1.361831] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    1.361838] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: detected 2 ports
[    1.361865] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: irq 23, io base 0x00001020
=1
[    1.370677] usb usb6: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    1.370679] usb usb6: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.0-4-amd64 uhci_hcd
[    1.370680] usb usb6: SerialNumber: 0000:01:04.4
[    1.370946] hub 6-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.370957] hub 6-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    1.375764] scsi host0: hpsa
[    1.390041] hpsa 0000:05:00.0: scsi 0:0:0:0: added RAID              HP       P410i            controller SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=1
[    1.390046] hpsa 0000:05:00.0: scsi 0:0:1:0: masked Direct-Access     HP       DG0146FARVU      PHYS DRV SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=0
[    1.390049] hpsa 0000:05:00.0: scsi 0:0:2:0: masked Direct-Access     HP       DG0146FARVU      PHYS DRV SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=0
[    1.390052] hpsa 0000:05:00.0: scsi 0:0:3:0: masked Direct-Access     HP       DG0146FAMWL      PHYS DRV SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=0
[    1.390055] hpsa 0000:05:00.0: scsi 0:0:4:0: masked Direct-Access     HP       DG0146FARVU      PHYS DRV SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=0
[    1.390059] hpsa 0000:05:00.0: scsi 0:0:5:0: masked Direct-Access     HP       DG0146FARVU      PHYS DRV SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=0
[    1.390062] hpsa 0000:05:00.0: scsi 0:0:6:0: masked Enclosure         PMCSIERA  SRC 8x6G        enclosure SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=0
[    1.390065] hpsa 0000:05:00.0: scsi 0:1:0:0: added Direct-Access     HP       LOGICAL VOLUME   RAID-5 SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=1
[    1.390953] scsi 0:0:0:0: RAID              HP       P410i            3.52 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.436056] scsi 0:1:0:0: Direct-Access     HP       LOGICAL VOLUME   3.52 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.479634] sd 0:1:0:0: [sda] 1146733360 512-byte logical blocks: (587 GB/547 GiB)
[    1.479893] sd 0:1:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    1.479896] sd 0:1:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 6b 00 00 08
[    1.480050] sd 0:1:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.487483] uhci_hcd 0000:01:04.4: Controller not stopped yet!
[    1.488059]  sda: sda1 sda2 < sda5 >
[    1.489654] sd 0:1:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.747319] random: fast init done
[    1.827342] usb 4-2: new low-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[    2.052396] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1a2c, idProduct=0b23
[    2.052397] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.052398] usb 4-2: Product: USB Keyboard
[    2.052399] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: USB
[    2.057890] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    2.091609] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.091610] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.092359] input: USB USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/0003:1A2C:0B23.0001/input/input3
[    2.151475] hid-generic 0003:1A2C:0B23.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [USB USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.2-2/input0
[    2.151687] input: USB USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.1/0003:1A2C:0B23.0002/input/input4
[    2.211416] hid-generic 0003:1A2C:0B23.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [USB USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.2-2/input1
[    2.215428] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2532.613 MHz
[    2.215434] clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x2481921a2d0, max_idle_ns: 440795281605 ns
[    3.239675] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    4.423608] floppy0: no floppy controllers found
[    4.423617] work still pending
[    4.473615] PM: Starting manual resume from disk
[    4.473619] PM: Hibernation image partition 8:5 present
[    4.473619] PM: Looking for hibernation image.
[    4.473771] PM: Image not found (code -22)
[    4.473773] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
[    4.735756] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    5.443893] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[    5.508005] systemd[1]: systemd 232 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN)
[    5.508263] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[    5.509793] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <debian>.
[    5.934311] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    5.934409] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    5.934461] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    5.934648] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[    5.939400] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[    5.939628] systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
[    5.940316] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
[    6.227772] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    6.339848] systemd-journald[219]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    6.689837] pcc-cpufreq: (v1.10.00) driver loaded with frequency limits: 1600 MHz, 2533 MHz
[    6.980374] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
[    6.995088] ipmi message handler version 39.2
[    7.020156] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input5
[    7.020160] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    7.020269] ipmi_si IPI0001:00: ipmi_si: probing via ACPI
[    7.020295] ipmi_si IPI0001:00: [io  0x0ca2-0x0ca3] regsize 1 spacing 1 irq 0
[    7.020296] ipmi_si: Adding ACPI-specified kcs state machine
[    7.020316] IPMI System Interface driver.
[    7.020336] ipmi_si 0000:01:04.6: probing via PCI
[    7.020431] ipmi_si 0000:01:04.6: [mem 0xeb9f0000-0xeb9f00ff] regsize 1 spacing 1 irq 21
[    7.020432] ipmi_si: Adding PCI-specified kcs state machine
[    7.020459] ipmi_si: probing via SMBIOS
[    7.020460] ipmi_si: SMBIOS: io 0xca2 regsize 1 spacing 1 irq 0
[    7.020461] ipmi_si: Adding SMBIOS-specified kcs state machine duplicate interface
[    7.020463] ipmi_si: probing via SPMI
[    7.020464] ipmi_si: SPMI: io 0xca2 regsize 2 spacing 2 irq 0
[    7.020465] ipmi_si: Adding SPMI-specified kcs state machine duplicate interface
[    7.020467] ipmi_si: Trying PCI-specified kcs state machine at mem address 0xeb9f0000, slave address 0x0, irq 21
[    7.026896] Floppy drive(s): fd0 is 1.44M
[    7.029384] EDAC MC0: Giving out device to module i7core_edac.c controller i7 core #0: DEV 0000:3f:03.0 (INTERRUPT)
[    7.029425] EDAC PCI0: Giving out device to module i7core_edac controller EDAC PCI controller: DEV 0000:3f:03.0 (POLLED)
[    7.029442] EDAC i7core: Driver loaded, 1 memory controller(s) found.
[    7.036538] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    7.037453] power_meter ACPI000D:00: Found ACPI power meter.
[    7.037474] power_meter ACPI000D:00: Ignoring unsafe software power cap!
[    7.066051] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000928-0x000000000000092F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000920-0x000000000000092F (\SGPE) (20160831/utaddress-247)
[    7.066058] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    7.066093] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[    7.068594] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input6
[    7.092864] scsi 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 12
[    7.092898] sd 0:1:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    7.129569] hpwdt 0000:01:04.0: HPE Watchdog Timer Driver: NMI decoding initialized, allow kernel dump: ON (default = 1/ON)
[    7.129628] hpwdt 0000:01:04.0: HPE Watchdog Timer Driver: 1.4.0, timer margin: 30 seconds (nowayout=0).
[    7.129631] iTCO_vendor_support: vendor-support=0
[    7.149381] iTCO_wdt: Intel TCO WatchDog Timer Driver v1.11
[    7.149404] iTCO_wdt: unable to reset NO_REBOOT flag, device disabled by hardware/BIOS
[    7.217942] [drm] Initialized
[    7.274787] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[    7.494159] CRAT table not found
[    7.494160] Finished initializing topology ret=0
[    7.494182] kfd kfd: Initialized module
[    7.494621] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (RV100 0x1002:0x515E 0x103C:0x31FB 0x02).
[    7.494635] [drm] register mmio base: 0xEBAF0000
[    7.494636] [drm] register mmio size: 65536
[    7.494747] radeon 0000:01:03.0: VRAM: 128M 0x00000000E0000000 - 0x00000000E7FFFFFF (64M used)
[    7.494749] radeon 0000:01:03.0: GTT: 512M 0x00000000C0000000 - 0x00000000DFFFFFFF
[    7.494759] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=128M, BAR=128M
[    7.494760] [drm] RAM width 16bits DDR
[    7.494805] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 1019044 kiB
[    7.494805] [TTM] Initializing pool allocator
[    7.494811] [TTM] Initializing DMA pool allocator
[    7.494835] [drm] radeon: 64M of VRAM memory ready
[    7.494835] [drm] radeon: 512M of GTT memory ready.
[    7.494845] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 131072, num gpu pages 131072
[    7.515364] [drm] PCI GART of 512M enabled (table at 0x0000000079F80000).
[    7.515461] radeon 0000:01:03.0: WB disabled
[    7.515466] radeon 0000:01:03.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x00000000c0000000 and cpu addr 0xffff9b94f9f16000
[    7.515472] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    7.515473] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    7.515487] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[    7.515501] [drm] Loading R100 Microcode
[    7.516002] kvm: VM_EXIT_LOAD_IA32_PERF_GLOBAL_CTRL does not work properly. Using workaround
[    7.525836] radeon 0000:01:03.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/R100_cp.bin
[    7.526729] [drm] radeon: ring at 0x00000000C0001000
[    7.526774] [drm] ring test succeeded in 1 usecs
[    7.564987] random: crng init done
[    7.600992] Adding 2084860k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:2084860k FS
[    8.039740] [drm] ib test succeeded in 0 usecs
[    8.040013] [drm] No TV DAC info found in BIOS
[    8.040057] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[    8.040057] [drm] Connector 0:
[    8.040058] [drm]   VGA-1
[    8.040060] [drm]   DDC: 0x60 0x60 0x60 0x60 0x60 0x60 0x60 0x60
[    8.040060] [drm]   Encoders:
[    8.040061] [drm]     CRT1: INTERNAL_DAC1
[    8.040062] [drm] Connector 1:
[    8.040063] [drm]   VGA-2
[    8.040064] [drm]   DDC: 0x6c 0x6c 0x6c 0x6c 0x6c 0x6c 0x6c 0x6c
[    8.040064] [drm]   Encoders:
[    8.040065] [drm]     CRT2: INTERNAL_DAC2
[    8.112057] [drm] fb mappable at 0xE0040000
[    8.112058] [drm] vram apper at 0xE0000000
[    8.112058] [drm] size 1081344
[    8.112059] [drm] fb depth is 8
[    8.112059] [drm]    pitch is 1408
[    8.112243] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    8.275849] CE: hpet increased min_delta_ns to 20115 nsec
[    8.277711] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48
[    8.290095] radeon 0000:01:03.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[    8.315952] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.49.0 20080528 for 0000:01:03.0 on minor 0
[   10.055900] floppy0: no floppy controllers found
[   10.055910] work still pending
[  117.317805] ipmi_si: There appears to be no BMC at this location
[  117.333899] ipmi_si: Trying ACPI-specified kcs state machine at i/o address 0xca2, slave address 0x0, irq 0
[  227.432041] ipmi_si: There appears to be no BMC at this location
[  916.470599] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  916.620311] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5567
[  916.620314] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  916.620315] usb 1-5: Product: Cruzer Blade
[  916.620317] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[  916.620318] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 4C530001310824123262
[  916.689497] usb-storage 1-5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  916.689576] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-5:1.0
[  916.689647] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  916.698330] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  917.692480] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Blade     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  917.693535] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  917.694156] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 15232000 512-byte logical blocks: (7.80 GB/7.26 GiB)
[  917.695784] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  917.695786] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  917.696981] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  917.707913]  sdb: sdb1
[  917.712525] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  961.503709] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
```

Comment: The command is absolutely alright, my guess is that there's a problem with the path and/or USB.

Comment: Can you show me the correct command (as I am a newbie in linux) on how to copy the firmware to /lib/firmware/

Comment: Yes sure. 1. find out what device it is with `lsblk`. Then mount it `mount /dev/sdbX mountpoint/` and then you run your `dpkg -i /path/to/firmware` command.

Comment: Thank you for helping me..I did as per your instruction but it seems that I am not getting right :( ............please see the picture.https://imgur.com/a/LZGqD

Comment: the `X` is a variable, put in `/dev/sdb1` instead of `/dev/sdbX` :)

Comment: I mounted the usb using this command mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt. It was successful :)

Comment: But when I tried this command dpkg -i /path/to/firmware, nothing happened. Should I write exactly /path/ and /to/ in the terminal? I am confuse, is /path/ a usb(sdb1)? and is /to/ a destination folder? Please bear with me. thanks..

Comment: Done..I installed the missing firmware :) ... please check the result https://imgur.com/a/sn5iP Is this means I did it and installed it correctly? if yes why is it that when i check the network using this command ip route get 1.2.3.4 it says "RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable". I connected already the LAN cable but still no network.

Comment: Yes, you did a good job :) regarding the network: I can't tell from remote, I don't know your settings unfortunately. But network is unreachable means that you probably have no default route.

Comment: Thank you. How can I have a default route? I run the command dmesg | grep -i ethernet to check whether the firmware is loaded but the output is "dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted"

Comment: Sorry I run again  the command with root dmesg | grep -i ethernet to check whether the firmware is loaded but no output. please check the image https://imgur.com/a/Q71aj

Comment: I installed the this firmware but nothing happened (firmware-netxen_20161130-3_all.deb). Another firmware I installed but again no luck (firmware-netxen_20170823-1_all.deb). I found another firmware thinking that this may help, this firmware is rpm and i converted to deb but also it did not work out. When i installed, it gives me an error "dependency problem: leaving unconfigured". (hp-firmware-nic-netxen-5.6.8-1.1.x86_64.rpm)

Comment: after running dmesg I received this error. [    1.331446] QLogic/NetXen Network Driver v4.0.82
[    1.331548] netxen_nic 0000:06:00.0: 2MB memory map
[    1.331679] netxen_nic 0000:06:00.0: Flash fw[4.0.406] is < min fw supported[4.0.505]. Please update firmware on flash
[    1.331718] netxen_nic: probe of 0000:06:00.0 failed with error -22

Answer (score 1):

You right on track with that command:

```
dpkg -i /path/to/firmware-netxen_20161130-3_all.deb
```

In case you run into dependencies issues run:

```
apt-get update -f
```

Then try the install again.

Please see: `man dpkg` for more information about `dpkg`. Look at the examples at the bottom.

Comment: Debian uses su to become Root and does not have sudo by default...

Answer (score 0):

> netxen_nic 0000:06:00.0: Flash fw[4.0.406] is < min fw supported[4.0.505]. Please update firmware on flash

The firmware on the network card needs an update (flashed) to be compatible with non ancient kernels. But the makefile to build the flash updater is only compatible with ancient kernels. Plus the provided nxflash script needs some editing.

- /bin/bash instead of /bin/sh
- replace /sbin/lspci with $LSPCI

You can find more details at http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=103825#p497081